# MATLAB: Ignoring Specific Columns in a Matrix when Carrying Out a Loop

Tags: matlab, calculated-columns

so far I have this:

```
for l=1:50
    %# matrix of distances between terminal nodes, index of column represents 
    %# where the searcher is going from and the index of the row represents 
    %# where the searcher is going to
    d = [
    10  2 2 3 3 2 4 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 4 4;
    10 10 2 5 5 4 6 7 7 6 6 6 5 5 6 6;
    10 2 10 5 5 4 6 7 7 6 6 6 5 5 6 6;
    10 5 5 10 2 3 7 8 8 7 7 7 6 6 7 7;    
    10 5 5 2 10 3 7 8 8 7 7 7 6 6 7 7;    
    10 4 4 3 3 10 6 7 7 6 6 6 5 5 6 6;    
    10 6 6 7 7 6 10 3 3 2 4 4 5 5 6 6;    
    10 7 7 8 8 7 3 10 2 3 5 5 6 6 7 7;    
    10 7 7 8 8 7 3 2 10 3 5 5 6 6 7 7;
    10 6 6 7 7 6 2 3 3 10 4 4 5 5 6 6;
    10 6 6 7 7 6 4 5 5 4 10 2 5 5 6 6;
    10 6 6 7 7 6 4 5 5 4 2 10 5 5 6 6;
    10 5 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 10 2 3 3;
    10 5 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 2 10 3 3;
    10 6 6 7 7 6 6 7 7 6 6 6 3 3 10 2;
    10 6 6 7 7 6 6 7 7 6 6 6 3 3 2 10
    ];

    i=1;                         %# start the searcher at the origin    
    h=5;    
    t=0;                         %# start time of the game
    k=find(d(i,:)==min(d(i,:))); %# position closest nodes
    j=randsample(k,1,true);      %# randomly selects closest node if multiple nodes within closest distance
    c=min(d(i,:));

    while j~=h       %# while the searcher is not in the same position as the hider
        d(:,j)=[];   %# delete the column corresponding to the searchers position so he cannot return here

        %# want to ignore all previous positions not delete them!        
        i=j;                        %# reset the searchers current position        
        k=find(d(i,:)==min(d(i,:))) %# find the new minimum distance        
        p=rand(1)*length(k);        %# randomly select an index of k        
        q=floor(p)+1                %# take the integer part of k        
        j=k(q)                      %# randomly select from all the closest nodes        
        t=t+min(d(i,:))+c;          %# calculate cumulative time for paths traveled
    end

    Found(l)=j-1 %# show position where the hider was found (relate matrix index to node index)
    Time(l)=t    %# show time taken for the searcher to find the hider
end
```

So the elements in `d` are the distance between two positions, represented by the row and column position, then the aim is to reach column 5 (`h`) by traveling the shortest distances between positions.

The problem I have is that I am currently deleting each column as it is searched for the minimum distance, this is then redefining the index of the column and so when `h` is either not being reached or it is not the correct `h`. How can I ignore rows already searched in the 'while' loop?

Any help will be gratefully received, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array `flags=zeros(16,1)` and turn `flag(i)=1` when you visit the row. Then you can check whether a row was flagged.

Comment: Thank you, I shall give that a try.